# Class descriptor 'Landroid/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsCallback/;' cannot be represented in dex format

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I updated my android studio to version `3.3 canary 13` (latest as of this writing). I was prompted to update my project's gradle version and I updated it to version `3.3.0-alpha13`

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'`

Now when i tried to run my project, it failed with an error

`Error: Class descriptor 'Landroid/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsCallback/;' cannot be represented in dex format.`

I tried to invalidate cache, clean and rebuild the project but nothing worked. Below is my app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: please double check with `androidx` import . it might be causing the issue

Comment: @TejasPandya I managed to solve the problem. see answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to try `./gradlew build --stacktrace` command and saw that `ICustomTabsCallback` class is being used by `androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc01` library.

```
> Transform browser.aar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc01) with DexingTransform
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Class descriptor \u0027Landroid/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsCallback/;\u0027 cannot be represented in dex format.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Class descriptor \u0027Landroid/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsCallback/;\u0027 cannot be represented in dex format.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I then used `./gradlew app:dependencies` command to see if there is conflict in dependencies and i found the error.

```
 +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    \--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc01
|         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0
|         +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
```

The above extract shows some of dependencies for `debugCompileClasspath` configuration. We can see that `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` contains `androidx.browser:browser` as a transitive dependency.

`androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0` means that version `1.0.0` will be used instead of version `1.0.0-rc01` but this is not the case for `androidx.browser:browser`. version `1.0.0-rc01` will be used instead of version `1.0.0`

To solve this error, i just removed the transitive dependencies by adding the below block of code in my app's `build.gradle`

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.browser', module: 'browser'
}
```

So my app's build.gradle will look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    //....
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.browser', module: 'browser'
}

dependencies {
// ....
}
```

After that, i just synced,cleaned and rebuild my project.

**UPDATE**

If the answer din't solve your problem, The other option is to use android studio stable version (3.2.1 as per this writing) and gradle 3.2.1 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

Comment: That's not a valid solution, if you are actually using customtabs.

Comment: @Marius I'm not using customtabs. As you can see, it's in the library `androidx.browser:browser` which is a transitive dependency of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` library

Comment: @EdijaeCrusar I am using them. I ended up just downgrading to previous version.

Comment: The solution above excluding `androidx.browser` allowed me to build the app, however the app no longer connects to the network. It seems like it is related as this was not an issue before.

Comment: I ended up versioning down to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha12'` and moved to the stable version of Android Studio **3.2** and now my app is up and running.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz My app is also connecting to the network and I'm able to make back-end calls. I haven't experienced such kind of error. maybe it's related to something else but I'm glad you found a way out of the problem.

Comment: Like @Marius is saying, this is not a valid solution but more of a work around.
This answer also ended up killing my networking.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra The problem is related to something else. `androidx.browser:browser`  provides APIs to support adding and managing custom tabs in your apps. check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.browser/browser and [https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#custom-tabs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#custom-tabs)

Comment: @Adam Hurwitz When I downgrade my app crashes as soon as it tries to inflate Materials TabLayout, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra - May you please create a new StackOverflow regarding the downgrade from the alpha version of Android Studio to stable 3.2. Then I can include my build.gradle configuration in the answer portion for you to compare with. If you do so, share the link in the comments here with my name tagged so I get a notification.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra implement  my answer and add this `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'` to your app's dependencies block

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra Let me know if it has worked on your side

Comment: @Edijae Crusar I'm currently at work but I will see if I'm able to try this tonight. I will let you know.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz I'm going to try the other solution first. I'll let you know if it didn't work and mad a new SO.

Comment: @EdijaeCrusar Your solution didn't completely solved my issue. After applying  your solution it would successfully build but once I navigated to my page that contained my Tabs the app crashed. That error said something about a missing property on the component. Applying a MaterialComponent theme solved this. Then I could also safely remove your solution. So I've posted that as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52745771/1093801

Comment: Like @AdamHurwitz said, this isn't a valid answer as you're removing a transitive dependency which might break the library you're relying on. This is a bug with the AGP 3.3.0-alpha13, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117145286

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has had this problem with getting AndroidX to work with the Jetifier then you have a couple of options.

If you are able to update your Gradle and plugin version then you should do; this is a bug that was addressed 3.3.0 and above. You can see what combination of gradle/plugin versions you need here; https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.

In my case I was tied to Gradle 4.6 and it's highest plugin version of 3.2.1 (i'm using Unity 2017.4 LTS). In which can I applied the workaround found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117145286#comment24) by adding the following to my build.gradle file;

```
buildscript {    
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
    }
}
```

Credit to @TheHebrewHammer in the comments above for pointing this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your theme in your `styles.xml` so that it extends one of the MaterialComponents theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Other options:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
```

More about this:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Answer (score 0):

Looks like lots of us get similar errors for different reasons. In my case, I was returning null inside the `key` compose function. Looked like this

```
key(item.id) {
  if (shouldNotBeVisible) {
    return null
  }
}
```

Oversimplified but you get the idea. Found about this doing `./gradlew build --stacktrace` as recommended above, and the stacktrace pointed to the composable function with the issue.